# What is the REST URI that does the same as the CAML Query shown here

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, error, caml-query

What is the REST URI that does the same as the CAML Query shown here

This CAML Query (works great):

```
CamlBuilder().View().RowLimit(5000).Query().Where().TextField('ItemDescription').Contains('laptop').And().TextField('ItemRef').NotEqualTo('0000000000')
```

This is what I have tried, to no avail:

```
.../Items?$filter=(substringof('laptop',ItemDescription)) AND (ItemRef ne '0000000000')
```

The error I get from SharePoint is:

> The expression "(substringof('laptop',ItemDescription)) AND (ItemRef ne '0000000000')" is not valid."

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the data type of "ItemDescription" and "ItemRef" columns?

Comment: Both are type text fields.  It seems the problem was the capital AND... So silly :) its often times the simple things that get us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing and in the filter to lower case.

`.../Items?$filter=(substringof('laptop',ItemDescription)) and (ItemRef ne '0000000000')`

Comment: As simple as that -- I must have been tired.  Fixed!  Thank you very much!